# Fastest way to move a directory in Android?

Tags: android

What is the fastest way to move a directory in Android?  In most, but not all cases, the source and destination are located on the same sdcard file system.

Current, my code goes through the entire directory structure, and copy the content of each file into a  new file with the same name in the new location.  It then verifies the file size matches, then deletes the source file.

For each file, I current run (with additional exception handling):

```
    try{
      source = new FileInputStream(fileFrom).getChannel();
      destination = new FileOutputStream(fileTo).getChannel();
      destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
      source.close();
      destination.close();
    }
```

This seems to be slow as well as way to much computational work for what I expect could maybe be a simple instant "node modification" at the raw file system level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as Files are on the same filesystem you can actually move them [File#renameTo(File)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29).

```
if (!fileFrom.renameTo(fileTo)) {
    copy(fileFrom, fileTo);
    // delete(fileFrom);
}
```

Comment: You can do this but check that the return value isn't false. If it is false then copy the files/folders.

Comment: Accepted as the answer.  Thank you.  10 minute copy became a 10 second copy.  ;-)

Comment: You didn't define the method copy.

Comment: @coolcool1994 Indeed. I left that out since you can find many examples across the web. For example one in OP's question

Comment: Do you absolutely need copy method? I mean doesn't renameTo already move the file? What is the purpose of having the copy method? What is it suppose to do? You did not define it.

Comment: @coolcool1994 `renameTo` can only rename {files | directories} if `fileFrom` and `fileTo` are within the same filesystem. Like you can't rename a file from being on your harddrive onto some USB thumbdrive. The method returns `false` in that case and you have to fallback to manually copying everything over to the new location and deleting at the old place afterwards. Samples of `copy` & `delete` can be found here: https://subversivebytes.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/java-copy-directory-recursive-delete/

Comment: Oh I see thank you for clarifying. For me I was just moving files in internal storage only. It just all works with renameTo. Edit your answer so I can up vote it.