# Android: best practice ? , when copying multiple files from one folder to another , it takes much time ,

Tags: android, performance, inputstream, outputstream, fileoutputstream

i am using below code to copy multiple files from one folder to another , but it takes too much time , it is requested is their any best practice to implement to increase speed. i will be grateful.( Note: i am not moving files )

```
void copyFile(File sourceLocation, File targtLocation) throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.exists()) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            new File(String.valueOf(targtLocation)).delete();
            out = new FileOutputStream(targtLocation);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();

        sourceLocation.delete();
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(sourceLocation));
        sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
        Log.e("debug", "Copy file successful.");

    } else {
        Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to move a directory in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320655/fastest-way-to-move-a-directory-in-android)

Comment: but i can't move file from internal storage to SD card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last did it. when i use BufferedOutputStream and BufferedInputStream the processing time was half. Unlike input/outputstream,  it do not call  the underlying system for each byte read/write. instead it call once and buffer those streams .

```
void copyFileFast1(File sourceLocation, File targtLocation) throws IOException {

        if (sourceLocation.exists()) {
            FileInputStream fin = null;
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            Log.i("debug","source "+sourceLocation);
            Log.i("debug","des "+targtLocation);
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                new File(String.valueOf(targtLocation)).delete();
                fout = new FileOutputStream(targtLocation);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(fin);
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            fin.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
            fout.close();

            sourceLocation.delete();
            Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(sourceLocation));
            sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
            Log.e("debug", "Copy file successful.");

        } else {
            Log.v("debug", "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **destination.transferFrom()** method to do fast file transfer

```
  public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
        destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also use `FileUtils.copyFile()` method

```
 String sourcePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TongueTwister/tt_temp.3gp";
        File source = new File(sourcePath);

        String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/TongueTwister/tt_1A.3gp";
        File destination = new File(destinationPath);
        try 
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```